# Matrix-vector multiplication in Kyber implementation

Tags: implementation, kyber

I took a look at the implementation of Kyber, which can be found in this [GitRepo](https://github.com/pq-crystals/kyber/tree/main/ref). I made a small discovery in the [indcpa.c](https://github.com/pq-crystals/kyber/blob/main/ref/indcpa.c) in the function `indcpa_keypair`, starting at line 205, which I can't quite interpret. The line is given below.

```
  // matrix-vector multiplication
  for(i=0;i<KYBER_K;i++) {
    polyvec_basemul_acc_montgomery(&pkpv.vec[i], &a[i], &skpv);
    poly_tomont(&pkpv.vec[i]);
  }
```

What we do there, we perform a matrix-vector multiplication of the matrix `a` with the vector `skpv`, which is done via the first line in the loop. Then, in the next line, `pkpv` is converted into the Montgomery representation with `poly_tomont`. Why are we doing the latter?

**My thoughts**:

- From the description of `polyvec_basemul_acc_montgomery`, see line 202 [here](https://github.com/pq-crystals/kyber/blob/main/ref/polyvec.c), we got: "Pointwise multiply elements of `a` and `b`, accumulate into `r`, and multiply by 2^-16". If I remember correctly, the Montgomery factor was $2^{16}$, so if `polyvec_basemul_acc_montgomery` produces an output that is multiplied by $2^{-16}$, then we have to work with `poly_tomont` afterwards (because we multiply by $2^{16}$ again when converting to Montgomery representation) to get rid of the $2^{-16}$, right?

Further question:

- In conext of `polyvec_basemul_acc_montgomery`, however, it is another question where the multiplication by $2^{-16}$ takes place...